# Is there any software or library available to draw screws in 3 dimensions in C, C++, Java, or Ruby?

Tags: java, c++, c, ruby, 3d

Is there any software or library available to draw screws in 3 dimensions in C, C++, Java, or Ruby?

Comment: You mean as in M10 bolts or as in top shelf videos?

Comment: Yes Rich , M10 bolts , if i specify the  dimensions and number of threads to be drawn , it should display dynamically draw the dimension of the bolt and number of threads specified .

Comment: Why do you need to do this programmatically?  Why can't you just use CAD?

Comment: @Pesto i need dynamism in creating a screw not just drawing, See if i change the dimensions it should change the dimension dynamically and also the threads in the screw  , for example if i say thread is 3 then it should create a Screw/bolt  with specified dimension and 3 threads . This is my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not familiar with the topic but, May be this could help. [Here](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/sketchup/)